# Adding Comments to a Post in JS

Tags: javascript, html, comments, blogs

Im trying to add a way to leave a comment for every blog that I create. My thought process was to wrap my postTitle and postContent in a div. Then pass in HTML form js of a commentForm that has access to ever id of a blog.

The problem is that blogCard.appendChild(postTitle, postContent) isn't actually wrapping the attributes in a div and renderCommentForm() is returning a string to the frontend instead of being HTML.

Thank you for any advice you may offer to figure out how to create a comment for every blog post via forEach.

```
 const postContainer = document.querySelector("#posts-container")
         console.log(posts)
        posts.data.forEach(function(post){
            
            const newPostTitle = document.createElement('h4')
            newPostTitle.innerText = post.attributes.title 
            const postTitle = postContainer.appendChild(newPostTitle)

            const newPostContent = document.createElement('p')
            newPostContent.innerText = post.attributes.content
            const postContent = postContainer.appendChild(newPostContent)
            

            const button = document.createElement('button')
            button.id= `${post.id}`
            button.innerText = 'Leave a Comment'
            postContainer.appendChild(button)


            const blogPostCard = document.createElement('div') 
            const newBlog = blogPostCard.appendChild(postTitle, postContent)
            postContainer.appendChild(newBlog)
   
            const commentForm = document.createElement('div')
            commentForm.innerText = renderCommentForm(button.id)
            postContainer.appendChild(commentForm)

            

            button.addEventListener('click', function(e){
                renderCommentForm(button.id)
            });
             

             function renderCommentForm(postId){
        console.log(postId)
        return (
        `<form id='comment-form' class=""> 
            <input id='comment' type="text" name='comment' value='' placeholder= 'Comment Here'/>
        </form>`)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

commentForm.innerText = renderCommentForm(button.id)

should be
commentForm.innerHtml = renderCommentForm(button.id)

See https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp

Comment: Thank You, I changed it to html but it is still isnt rendering...

Comment: Thank you, that part worked when I changed it to commentForm.innerHTML = renderCommentForm(button.id). But the blogPostCard 'div' still isn't being created for some reason.

Comment: @Echelon1089 well to fix that I would first cleanup your variables. For instance you are declaring postContent as appendChild(newPostContent) and then in
const newBlog = blogPostCard.appendChild(postTitle, postContent)
you trying to appendChild this constant again. I would also try to put that JS into the browser console, when being on the actual page to see if it throws any errors.
A fix could look like this:
const postContent = "<div><p>Lorem Ipsum</p></div>";
blogPostCard.appendChild(postContent);

The numerous "useless" constants and functions won't help much with debugging. ;)